# This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times

Tags: php

When I'm trying to add a new financial aid:

```
if (!$row['count']) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = language("financials-card-no-articles-error", $_SESSION['lang']);
    header('Location: financials.php?manage=add&lang='.$selectedLang);
    die();
```

Then it shows this on my browser:

> This page isn’t working: localhost redirected you too many times.

Comment: You appear to be redirecting from a page back to itself. Your `$row['count']` is never set, so the `if` conditional gets triggered every time the page is loaded, and you get redirected again. Thus, you end up in an infinite loop. You'll need to break out of your conditional logic at some point.

Comment: You'll have to show more of your code for us to be able to suggest the correct course of action. As it stands the code shown just confirms there is a potential for the infinite loop

Comment: Show also code from financials.php as as it may be involved in the back and forth redirection as well.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfwVg.jpg